# A question on Dixon's proof for the global Cauchy Formula

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I am following Dixon's proof for the global form of the Cauchy Forula and one of the first things one has to prove is that

[image]

is continious, where $f$ is analytic. The book I am following (Lang's Complex Analysis) mentions that the proof for the continuity off the diagonal is obvious, however I can't seem to able to prove it.

**My attempt:**

Select $(a,b)$ close to $(z,\zeta)$ s.t. $|z-a|< \delta _1$ and $|\zeta-b|< \delta_2$ where $\delta _1 , \delta _2 >0$. Then

$$|g(z,\zeta)-g(a,b)|=|\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|$$

now if I was to use the triangle inequality I can take care of the bottom terms by selecting $\lambda=min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ but I then can't use the continiuity of $f$ to get that $g$ is continious off the diagonal. Any thoughts of how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z\ne\zeta$, $g$ is the quotient of two continuous (actually analytic) functions, hence continuous.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I was wondering is it possible to prove this dirrectly through the epsilon delta notation?

Comment: Well, it must be.  Umm, if you get stuck perhaps look up "quotient of continuous functions".  As long as the denominator function is not zero, you'll get another continuous function.  I might be tempted to use the limit point definition here, also.